# Find k such that f is density function

Tags: probability, integration

I have the following function: $f_X(x, \theta) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       k/x^3 & : x \leq \theta \\
       0 & : x > \theta
     \end{array}
   \right.$ and $\theta >0$.

I should find $k$ such that $f$ is a density function.

What i know: $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f_X(x,\theta)dx$ = 1, then $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\theta}kx^{-3}dx = 1$. The last integral solves to $-\displaystyle\frac{k}{2x^2}$ then it must be $-\displaystyle\frac{k}{2\theta^2} = 1$ and then $k = - 2\theta^2$.

Here's the issue: shouldn't $f_X$ be equal or greater than 0?.
I could consider separately what happens when $x<0$ and $0<x<\theta$ and find $k$ for both, but this implies i should solve $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{0}kx^{-3}dx$ and the last one doesn't converge.

What's wrong with what i'm trying to do?.

Comment: There must be a typo. The integral from $-\infty$ to $\theta$ where $\theta\ge 0$ does not converge. By the way, you also integrated incorrectly. An antiderivative is $(-1/2)kx^{-2}$. But fixing that won't make the integral converge.

Comment: A pretty standard type of distribution has $k/x^3$ for $x\ge \theta$. That is presumably what is intended, though the one given with $\theta\lt 0$ would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had a mistake. Please see this: $$\displaystyle f_\Theta(\theta)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f_X(x,\theta)dx= \frac{-k}{2\theta^2} $$
And also :
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f_\Theta(\theta)d\theta=1 \quad \Rightarrow \frac k2(\frac1{\theta})_0^\infty=1$$ which is not possible. So I think, there is no *constant* $k$ making this a density function.

Answer (score 1):

For every $\theta\gt0$, the unique constant $k$ such that the function $f$ defined by $f(x)=k/x^3$ if $x\gt\theta$ and $f(x)=0$ otherwise is a density, is $k=2\theta^2$ since 
$$
\int_\theta^\infty (k/x^3)\mathrm dx=\left[-k/(2x^2)\right]_\theta^\infty=k/(2\theta^2).
$$
Thus, the answer to *What's wrong with what i'm trying to do?* is probably that you miscopied the text of the exercise.